# No cooperation between readFile & IO monad when programming pointlessly

Tags: haskell, io, monads, pointfree

Why do countInFile1 & countInFile3 have compiler errors, when countInFile0 & countInFile2 do not.  All four are the same thing.

```
count :: String -> String -> Int
count w = length . filter (==w) . words

present :: String -> String -> IO String
present w = return . show . count w

-- VALID: pointed readFile, regular present
countInFile0 :: String -> FilePath -> IO ()
countInFile0 w f = putStrLn =<< present w =<< readFile f

-- INVALID: pointless readFile, regular present
countInFile1 :: String -> FilePath -> IO ()
countInFile1 w = putStrLn =<< present w =<< readFile

-- VALID: pointed readFile, inline present
countInFile2 :: String -> FilePath -> IO ()
countInFile2 w f = putStrLn =<< (return . show . count w) =<< readFile f

-- INVALID: pointless readFile, inline present
countInFile3 :: String -> FilePath -> IO ()
countInFile3 w = putStrLn =<< (return . show . count w) =<< readFile

main = do
  countInFile0 "bulldogs" "bulldogs.txt"
  countInFile1 "bulldogs" "bulldogs.txt"
  countInFile2 "bulldogs" "bulldogs.txt"
  countInFile3 "bulldogs" "bulldogs.txt"
```

Also why does countInFile3 have this additional error that countInFile1 does not:

```
example_one.hs:21:27:
    No instance for (Monad ((->) FilePath))
      arising from a use of `=<<'
    Possible fix:
      add an instance declaration for (Monad ((->) FilePath))
    In the expression:
        putStrLn =<< (return . show . count w) =<< readFile
    In an equation for `countInFile3':
        countInFile3 w
          = putStrLn =<< (return . show . count w) =<< readFile
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With both `countInFile1` and `countInFile3`, since you are composing three things of the form `a -> IO b`, you are thinking of the so-called Kleisli composition, the `<=<` from `Control.Monad`.  Try

```
 countInFile1 w = putStrLn <=< present w <=< readFile
 countInFile3 w = putStrLn <=< return . show . count w <=< readFile
```

Or you can write `countInFile3 w file = ... =<< readFile file`, as you do elsewhere. `readFile file` (with the parameter) is an `IO String`, so it can be passed along by `>>=` or `=<<` to any `String -> IO b`. But that isn't as swank as what you intended.  `readFile` just by itself is a `FilePath -> IO String` so it can be `>=>`'d with any `String -> IO b` to make a `FilePath -> IO b` and so on with a `b -> IO c`, etc. in your case ending with a `FilePath -> IO ()`

The second error comes from ghc trying to read `=<< readFile`, to do so it needs `readFile` to be m b for some monad m, so it settles on `Monad ((->) FilePath)` (this would actually make sense with `Control.Monad.Instances`, but would just delay getting the first error.)

If you add the `file` parameter to these it would be thus,

```
 countInFile1 w file = (putStrLn <=< present w <=< readFile) file
```

and it is possible that you are parsing `countInFile2` and `countInFile0` this way, while construing `=<<` as `<=<` when actually they are like so:

```
 countInFile0 w file = putStrLn =<< present w =<< (readFile file)
```

The difference is the same as that between

```
 f n = (even . (+1) . (*3)) n
```

or equivalently

```
 f   = even . (+1) . (3*)
```

and on the other hand

```
 f n = even $ (+1) $ 3 * n  -- cp. your 0 and 2
```

If you delete the `n` from both sides here

```
 f   = even $ (+1) $ (3*)  -- cp. your 1 and 3
```

you will get a type error akin to the ones you saw:

```
 No instance for (Integral (a0 -> a0)) arising from a use of `even'
```

Where you use `$` you need the parameter `n` -- as where you use `>>=` or `=<<` you need the parameter `file`.  With `.`, as with `<=<`, you don't.

Comment: +1: clear, well explained, demonstrates the lovely `<=<` which is what we all want, really, deep down inside.

Answer (score 8):

Function application has higher precedence than infix `=<<` operator.

So `f =<< g a` is equivalent to `f =<< (g a)` and not `(f =<< g) a`.